# Previous Button is not functioning properly React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a quiz page, where every time 3 questions will load one by one and on submit next 3 questions will load. On click of previous user can change his/her answer selected before clicking the submit button. But in the code the previous button is not functioning properly. After 5-6 click on previous button the user is redirected to next page. User can go on next page only after completing the quiz. but this is not happening. please help me out to figure out what is wrong in the code.

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const { questions, quiz, options } = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
    
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    console.log(currentQuestion[number] + "1q");
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    const classes = useStyles();
    

    // this is to get the questions from the history coming from redux store.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetchQuestions(history));
        }
    }, []);

      const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
        let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
        console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
        currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(currentSelection.value + "calculate score");
        // Set the new question count based on the current one
        setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
          return Math.min(
            current + 1,
            questions.length - 1
          );
        });
    };

    const previousQuestion = (current_question) => {
    let new_current_questions = Math.max(current_question - 1, 0);
    setCurrentQuestion(new_current_questions);
  };



function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     
    const valid = questions.some((q) => !q.value);
    console.log(valid + "questionsalpha");
    if (!valid) {
        dispatch(postQuiz({ responses: questions, id: quiz.id }, history));
    }
    
    setCurrentQuestion(0);

}
        return (
            !questions?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
                <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={1}>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {/* Only show the question if it's index is less than or equal to the current question */}
   <button type="submit" onClick={previousQuestion}>{current_question+1 ? 'Previous' : null}</button>
                        {questions.map((question, index) => (index <= currentQuestion ? (
                            <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl} data-hidden={question.number !== current_question[question.number]}>
                                <FormLabel component="legend">{question.question}</FormLabel>
                                <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value} onChange={(e) => handleRadioChange(question.number, e)}>
                                    {options.map((option) => 
                                        <FormControlLabel key={option.score} value={option.score} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} />
                                   )}
                                </RadioGroup>
                            </FormControl>
                        ) : null))}
                        <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                            Submit
                    </Button>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
            )
        );
    };
    
export default Quiz;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Previous Question button is inside of your form and you are not using event.preventDefault() in the previousQuestion function so while the previous question function is called the handleSubmit function is also being executed at the same time.

You also call the previousQuestion function without passing the current_question argument. You should grab the currentQuestion from state inside the function, and prevent the default action when clicking the Previous Question button.

You previousQuestion function should look like this:

```
const previousQuestion = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let new_current_questions = Math.max(currentQuestion - 1, 0);
  setCurrentQuestion(new_current_questions);
};
```

That should solve the issue you are having

Comment: Thanks @jwk549 you helped me and saved me from the silly blunder.
One more thing in between if a user refresh the page or on relogin it goes to the next page instead of maintaining the state where he left. There is something wrong I did can you please look that also. I am stuck. I used redux persist but its not working the way it should be. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515890/how-to-maintain-the-state-on-page-refresh-and-relogin

Comment: Sorry I can't help with Redux, I've never used it.

Comment: hey you already helped me, thanks. Can you please refer this to someone who knows, actually i am in middle of a project and i am stuck hard at the crucial stage. So needed a help. I think you can see if this problem can be solved without redux, I just need user to come to the same place where he last left. At every submit button clicked, the responses are saved in database.  @iwk549

Comment: Unless you need to store some complex or sensitive state I think you might be overengineering by using Redux. Just sticking the current question number in local storage and retrieving it upon refresh would be fine.

Comment: but storing the current question in local storage will not get the same current question if the user logs in different browser or somewhere else. SO this might not be a good option. so storing data in redux store will let it load from where user left if any other place the page is opened.
So if you can ask someone you know to help me out will be of great help. Thank You.

Comment: I'll ask around and see what I can come up with

Comment: hey thanks a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424306/how-to-handle-async-api-calls-to-backend-during-page-refresh-in-react-redux?rq=1

If anything from this can help. I am highly grateful to you for the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type of previous button to something else, probably a "button" type will be just fine.
Does it help?